# How to retrieve BSE/NSE listed stock's price from finance.yahoo.com

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, stock, yahoo-finance

I'm developing an application for stocks displaying through [finance.yahoo.com](http://in.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=BBDB.TO%20NT.TO%20GE%20MSFT%20INFY%20TTM&f=snl1d1t1ohgdrx) in Java using Spring framework.

But it only provides share values from NYSE, Nasdaq-NM, etc. How can I retrieve the values of share by specify NSE or BSE?

Comment: Currently using url for retrieving data as CSV is http://in.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=BBDB.TO+NT.TO+GE+MSFT+INFY+TTM&f=snl1d1t1ohgdrx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the components of BSE and NSE with these two links: http://in.finance.yahoo.com/gainers?e=bo and http://in.finance.yahoo.com/losers?e=bo (**Gainers and Losers**).
Once you have your full list of stocks, just use your link to retrieve data, for example:

```
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=BOBSL.BO,JAIPAN.BO,SANGHIIN.BO&f=snl1d1t1ohgdrx
```

You might want to check each ticker individually, and ensuring it does retrieve correct information though, eg `SOUTHINDBSL.BO` doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: @ Romain, how to take gainers & losers list as CSV

Comment: displaying N/A for NSE or BSE stocks